# JavaFX--Key events are getting intererrupted by Buttons

Tags: java, button, javafx, keyevent

I am a student in a second level OOP/Java programming class. We had an assignment to create a simple JavaFX interface that allows the user to draw in a pane using the arrow keys. It reminds me of an Etch-a-Sketch. This program worked fine, but I wanted to add buttons at the bottom to clear the screen so a user could start over without closing the program and an exit button, though it is a bit redundant with the top right X in the pane. In testing, the keypress of the down arrow passes into the HBox pane of the buttons, engaging a button and interrupts the drawing feature. Following that, keypress of the up arrow does not return the cursor to the drawing pane. Additionally, pressing left or right arrows (once the buttons are engaged) moves the focus between the buttons. I am looking for a way to restrict the key events to the drawing pane. I've pasted the code below without the imported libraries, but there are 15 of them including, LineTo, MoveTo, Button, Path... I can paste in if needed.

****edited code to reflect changes suggested by Slaw that worked
I now know that the code for the btClear button does not clear the pane and allow the user to begin drawing with a clean slate.****

```
public class LineToDrawPath extends Application {
private double bX = 100.0, bY = 100.0;
private double segment = 20.0;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(15,12,15,12));
    hBox.setSpacing(20);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Button btClear = new Button("Clear");
    btClear.setFocusTraversable(false); // effective solution
    Button btExit = new Button ("Exit");
    btExit.setFocusTraversable(false); // effective solution
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btClear, btExit);
    // Creating a Path object
    Path path = new Path(new MoveTo(bX, bY));

    path.setStrokeWidth(1.7);
    path.setStroke(Color.CHOCOLATE);

    pane.getChildren().add(path);

    path.setOnKeyPressed(e ->{
        if (e.getCode().isArrowKey()){
            switch (e.getCode()){
                case DOWN: bY += segment; break;
                case UP: bY -= segment; break;
                case LEFT: bX -= segment; break;
                case RIGHT: bX += segment; break;
            }
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo (bX, bY));
        }
    });

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(pane);
    borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(pane, Pos.CENTER);

    btClear.setOnAction(e -> {
        pane.getChildren().clear();
        pane.getChildren().add(path);
    });

    btExit.setOnAction(e ->
        System.exit(0)
    );



    // Create the scene object
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 400, 400); // places the pane in the scene
    primaryStage.setTitle("Draw a line with arrow keys");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // places the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // shows the window
    path.requestFocus();
    primaryStage.setResizable(false); // prevent user from resizing the window

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Call `setFocusTraversable(false)` on each `Button`. You could instead, or perhaps additionally, have `path` request focus whenever the user clicks inside it; to really indicate this to the user you could have different styles for  `path` depending on if it has the focus or not.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm still trying to understand how the path.requestFocus works. It seems to only work if it follows the setting of the scene. I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion there.

I tried the setFocusTraversable (false) on the hBox that the buttons are in, to no change. Will try applying to both buttons as suggested.

Comment: Okay! So  btClear.setFocusTraversable(false) and btExit.setFocusTraversable(false) worked! Thank you :) The arrow keyevents did not engage them. Now, my btClear button doesn't work, but the btExit does, so I must have altered the code a bit when I was experimenting with fixes. 
Thank you so much for your help, Slaw.

Comment: The reason `requestFocus()` only works once the `Node` is part of a `Scene` is because a `Node` having focus only makes sense in the context of a `Scene`. The `Scene` class has a [`focusOwner`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#focusOwnerProperty()) property that contains the currently focused `Node`. The focused `Node` is the one which receives any `KeyEvent`s (so long as the `Window` containing the `Scene` also has the focus). Only one `Node` can be focused per `Scene` at any given time.

Comment: This is not to be confused with [focus models](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/FocusModel.html) or [selection models](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html) such as those belonging to `ListView`, `TableView`, and `TabPane`. These models are in the context of the control and are a different mechanism to the `Scene#focusOwner` and [`Node#focused`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty()) properties.

Comment: not 100% sure, but try `e.consumer()` in your listener.

Comment: @Slaw--Thank you for explaining more. You have definitely helped me understand how requestFocus() works. I think what I will have to do to refocus on the pane with the path in it after "clearing the canvas" is to place the line creation part of the code in a method and call the method again in the btClear handler. I'm going to keep playing with it. You are the most helpful person I've run into on stack overflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a draw controller for my Etch-A-Sketch

```
public class ButtonDrawController implements Initializable {

@FXML private Pane paneMain,paneButtonDraw;
@FXML private ColorPicker colorpicker;
@FXML private Canvas canvasPaper;
@FXML private ChoiceBox<String> penSize;
@FXML private ChoiceBox<String> pickCircle;
@FXML private Label msg;
@FXML private ToggleButton tbnHelp;

public Stage stage;
GraphicsContext graphicsContext;
KeyCode keycode;
double X,Y;
double startAngle,arcExtent;
final Printer selectedPrinter = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();

@FXML
private void showHelp(ActionEvent e){
    if(tbnHelp.isSelected()){
        tbnHelp.setText("Hide Directions");
        tbnHelp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:darkgray;"
        +"-fx-border-style: solid outside;"
        +"-fx-border-width: 2;"
        +"-fx-border-color: blue;");

        String help = "\n\n" 
            +"                         These direction are for Draw with the Buttons\n\n" 
            +"To change Color or Pen Size see the Draw with the Mouse Directions.\n"
            +"When Drawing with Buttons if Color or Pen Size is changed it is best\n"
            +"to select a new draw position by clicking the Mouse on the paper.\n"
            +"ERASE and PRINT is covered in the Draw with Mouse Directions also.\n\n"
            +"Click the paper with the mouse to start drawing at that location.\n\n"
            +"To use the Pick Circle Type click the button and select the Circle Type.\n"
            +"To draw the Circle Type PRESS the Key Board 'A' key.\n"
            +"To draw a paint scattered type image PRESS the Key Board 'S' key.\n\n"
            +"                         Button Information for Drawing\n"
            +"-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
            +"To start drawing in the center of the paper PRESS the Key Board 'C' key.\n"
            +"To draw at other positions on the paper Click the Mouse at that location.\n\n"
            +"To draw a line UP - DOWN - LEFT - RIGHT  PRESS the Arrow Keys.\n\n"
            +"To draw a diagonal line PRESS the keys as described below.\n\n"
            +"UP and RIGHT"+"        "+"use the Numeric Key 9 or the Key Board 'H' key\n"
            +"UP and LEFT"+"           "+"use the Numeric Key 7 or the Key Board 'G' key\n"
            +"DOWN and RIGHT use the Numeric Key 3 or the Key Board 'N' key\n"
            +"DOWN and LEFT"+"     "+"use the Numeric Key 1 or the Key Board 'V' key\n\n";

        msg.setLayoutX(80);
        msg.setLayoutY(80);
        msg.setText(help);
        msg.setVisible(true);
        msg.toFront();
    }else{
        msg.setVisible(false);
        tbnHelp.setText("Show Directions");
        tbnHelp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgray;"
        +"-fx-border-style: solid outside;"
        +"-fx-border-width: 2;"
        +"-fx-border-color: blue;"); 
    }
}

@FXML
private void onPrint(ActionEvent e){
    printDialogSetup();   
}

private void printDialogSetup(){
    int lMargin =  (int) 0.2;//Printer sets margins as inches
    int rMargin =  (int) 0.2;//Need to convert inches to pixels ?
    int tMargin =  (int) 0.2;
    int bMargin =  (int) 0.2;
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    //PageLayout pageLayout = selectedPrinter.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER,PageOrientation.PORTRAIT,Printer.MarginType.EQUAL);
    PageLayout pageLayout = selectedPrinter.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, lMargin, rMargin, tMargin, bMargin);

    JobSettings jobSettings = job.getJobSettings();
    jobSettings.setPageLayout(pageLayout);

    boolean printed = job.printPage(canvasPaper);
        if (printed) {
        // End the printer job
        job.endJob();
        } 
}

@FXML
private void onPickCircle(MouseEvent e){

   pickCircle.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<? super Number>)(ov, old, newval) -> {
        Number idx = (Number)newval;

        switch(idx.intValue()){

        case 0: startAngle = 0;
                arcExtent = 0;
        break;
        case 1: startAngle = 0;// Circle
                arcExtent = 360;
        break;
        case 2: startAngle = 0;// N
                arcExtent = 180;
        break;
        case 3: startAngle = -90;// E
                arcExtent = 180;
        break;
        case 4: startAngle = 0;// S
                arcExtent = -180;
        break;
        case 5: startAngle = 90;//W
                arcExtent = 180;
        break;
        default: startAngle = 0;
                 arcExtent = 360;
        break;
        }
        });

    canvasPaper.requestFocus();
}

@FXML
private void onPenSize(MouseEvent e){

   penSize.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((ChangeListener<? super Number>)(ov, old, newval) -> {
        Number idx = (Number)newval;

        switch(idx.intValue()){

        case 0: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(1);
        break;
        case 1: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(2);
        break;
        case 2: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(3);
        break;
        case 3: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(4);
        break;
        case 4: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(5);
        break;
        case 5: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(8);//REAL big
        break;
        default: graphicsContext.setLineWidth(1);
        break;
        }
        graphicsContext.setLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
        });
    canvasPaper.requestFocus();
}

@FXML 
private void onPickColor(ActionEvent e){
    // change cursor more exact placement on the screen
    // graphicsContext.getCanvas().cursorProperty().set(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
    graphicsContext.setStroke(colorpicker.getValue());
    canvasPaper.requestFocus();
}

@FXML
private void onPressed(MouseEvent e){

    if(tbnHelp.isSelected()) {// Close the toggle button and HELP screen
        tbnHelp.setSelected(false);
        showHelp(null);
    }
    graphicsContext.getCanvas().cursorProperty().set(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
    graphicsContext.beginPath();
    graphicsContext.moveTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
    graphicsContext.setStroke(colorpicker.getValue());
    X = e.getX();
    Y = e.getY();
} 

@FXML
private void onDraw(KeyEvent ev){

    keycode = ev.getCode();

    if(X == 0 && Y == 0 ){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        alert.setTitle("Information");
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText("CLICK ON THE PAPER TO START DRAWING");
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
    }

    if(keycode == KeyCode.A){// Draws the Circle Type

        if(arcExtent == 0){
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            alert.setTitle("Information");
            alert.setHeaderText("");
            alert.setContentText("To Draw a Circle Type\n\n"
                                +"First Use Pick Circle Type");
            alert.showAndWait();   
            return;   
        }
        double XX = 120;
        graphicsContext.stroke();         
        graphicsContext.strokeArc(X, Y-60, XX, XX, startAngle, arcExtent, ArcType.OPEN);
    }

    if(keycode==KeyCode.S){

        graphicsContext.beginPath();
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+80, Y+80);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+40, Y+60);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+120, Y+20);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+180, Y+120);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-180, Y-120);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-80, Y+80);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-40, Y+60);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-120, Y+20);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-80, Y-80);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-40, Y-60);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X-120, Y-20);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+80, Y+80);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+40, Y+60);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+120, Y+20);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+20, Y-80);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+10, Y-60);
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X+50, Y-120);
        graphicsContext.setStroke(colorpicker.getValue());
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }

    if(keycode==KeyCode.C){// Center drawing position
        X = 296;
        Y = 381;
        graphicsContext.beginPath();
        graphicsContext.moveTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.setStroke(colorpicker.getValue());
    }

    if(keycode==KeyCode.NUMPAD9){// 9
        if(Y <= 21 || X >= 570){
            return;
        }
        X = X + 15.5;
        Y = Y - 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.H){// same as NUMPAD9
        if(Y <= 21 || X >= 570){
            return;
        }
        X = X + 15.5;
        Y = Y - 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.NUMPAD7){// 7
        if(Y <= 21 || X <= 19){
            return;
        }
        X = X - 15.5;
        Y = Y - 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.G){// same as NUMPAD7
        if(Y <= 21 || X <= 19){
            return;
        }
        X = X - 15.5;
        Y = Y - 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.NUMPAD1){// 1
        if(X <= 21 || Y >= 740){
            return;
        }
        X = X - 15.5;
        Y = Y + 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.V){// same as NUMPAD1
        if(X <= 21 || Y >= 740){
            return;
        }
        X = X - 15.5;
        Y = Y + 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }

    if(keycode==KeyCode.NUMPAD3){
        if(X >= 575 || Y >= 740){
            return;
        }
        X = X + 15.5;
        Y = Y + 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.N){// same as NUMPAD3
        if(X >= 575 || Y >= 740){
            return;
        }
        X = X + 15.5;
        Y = Y + 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.UP){
        if(Y <= 21){
            return;
        }
        X = X;
        Y = Y - 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.DOWN){
        if(Y >= 740){
            return;
        }
        X = X;
        Y = Y + 20;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke(); 
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.LEFT){
        if(X <= 21){
            return;
        }
        X = X - 20;
        Y = Y ;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
    if(keycode==KeyCode.RIGHT){
        if(X >= 570){
            return;
        }
        X = X + 20;
        Y = Y;
        graphicsContext.lineTo(X,Y);
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    }
}

@FXML
private void onErase(ActionEvent e){

    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    graphicsContext.clearRect(0, 0,
    graphicsContext.getCanvas().getWidth(),
    graphicsContext.getCanvas().getHeight());
    penSize.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    pickCircle.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    colorpicker.setValue(Color.RED);
}

@FXML
private void onBack(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{

    stage = (Stage)paneButtonDraw.getScene().getWindow();
    paneMain = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("etch.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(paneMain);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Etch A Sketch"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();
}

private void Init(){

    graphicsContext = canvasPaper.getGraphicsContext2D();
    colorpicker.setValue(Color.RED);
    graphicsContext.setStroke(colorpicker.getValue());
    penSize.getItems().addAll("1","2","3","4","5","6");
    penSize.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    // Set values for Choice Box set here only needs to happen once
    pickCircle.getItems().addAll("Click to Select","Circle","Half Circle N","Half circle E","Half Circle S","Half Circle W");
    pickCircle.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();// Makes first value visable in Choice Box
    tbnHelp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightgray;"
        +"-fx-border-style: solid outside;"
        +"-fx-border-width: 2;"
        +"-fx-border-color: blue;");
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    Init(); 
}
```

}